# Merging nodes via XSL based on conditional logic

Tags: xslt

I have an XML document that has several `<item>` elements.  Inside each, there might be one or more of the following elements: `<list>`, `<listAfter>`, and `<listBefore>`.  So, ignoring a lot of the extraneous elements, it might look like this:

```
<items>
  <item>
    <!-- ... various elements ... -->
    <list>Enhancements</list>
  </item>
  <item>
    <!-- ... various elements ... -->
    <listBefore>Enhancements</listBefore>
    <listAfter>Bugs</listAfter>
  </item>
  <item>
    <!-- ... various elements ... -->
    <list>Enhancements</list>
    <listAfter>Next Release</listAfter>
  </item>
  <item>
    <!-- ... various elements ... -->
    <listBefore>Bugs</listBefore>
  </item>
  <item>
    <!-- ... various elements ... -->
  </item>
</items>
```

I want to remove all of the extraneous `<list*>` elements and have one `<list>` element per `<item>`.  That element's value should follow this logic:

- Use the value of `<list>` if it's available.
- Otherwise, use the value of `<listAfter>` if it's available.
- Otherwise, use the value of `<listBefore>` if it's available.
- If none of these fields exist, use `No List` as the value.

Using my XML document above, here's what I would expect the output to look like:

```
<items>
  <item>
    <!-- ... various elements ... -->
    <list>Enhancements</list>
  </item>
  <item>
    <!-- ... various elements ... -->
    <list>Bugs</list>
  </item>
  <item>
    <!-- ... various elements ... -->
    <list>Enhancements</list>
  </item>
  <item>
    <!-- ... various elements ... -->
    <list>Bugs</list>
  </item>
  <item>
    <!-- ... various elements ... -->
    <list>No List</list>
  </item>
</items>
```

Other than using the Identity Transform to copy over all other elements, I'm not sure how to include this logic in a nice manner.  As always, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by overriding the identity template, and adding extra templates to match the criteria for the various list elements.

To match **listAfter** you wish to include in the output, you would do the following (i.e **listAfter** elements with no **list** element as a sibling)

```
<xsl:template 
   match="listAfter[not(preceding-sibling::list|following-sibling::list)]">
```

For the **listBefore**, you need to match them only if they have neither **list** not **listAfter** elements as siblings

```
<xsl:template 
  match="listBefore[not(
    preceding-sibling::list|following-sibling::list
    |preceding-sibling::listAfter|following-sibling::listAfter)]">
```

In other cases, you would ignore **listAfter** and **listBefore** elements:

```
<xsl:template match="listAfter|listBefore" />
```

Finally, you can match **item** elements with none of the various list elements as children like so:

```
<xsl:template match="item[not(list|listAfter|listBefore)]">
```

So, given the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:template match="listAfter[not(preceding-sibling::list|following-sibling::list)]">
      <list>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </list>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="listBefore[not(preceding-sibling::list|following-sibling::list|preceding-sibling::listAfter|following-sibling::listAfter)]">
      <list>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </list>
   </xsl:template>   

   <xsl:template match="listAfter|listBefore" />

   <xsl:template match="item[not(list|listAfter|listBefore)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <list>No List</list>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is applied to your source XML, the following is output:

```
<items>
   <item>
      <!-- ... various elements ... -->
      <list>Enhancements</list>
   </item>
   <item>
      <!-- ... various elements ... -->
      <list>Bugs</list>
   </item>
   <item>
      <!-- ... various elements ... -->
      <list>Enhancements</list>
   </item>
   <item>
      <!-- ... various elements ... -->
      <list>Bugs</list>
   </item>
   <item>
      <!-- ... various elements ... -->
      <list>No List</list>
   </item>
</items>
```

Comment: Awesome.  I'm still getting used to thinking in the right frame of mind for XSLT; thanks for your help!